# How to set the many instance variables in a class created by wsimport?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am writing a SOAP based client that will update fields in a database. One of the classes created by the java wsimport utility contains a representation of a table with each field in that table as a protected instance variable. Ex:

```
public class CustomObject1Data {

@XmlElement(name = "ModifiedDate")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar modifiedDate;
@XmlElement(name = "CreatedDate")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar createdDate;
@XmlElement(name = "ModifiedById")
protected String modifiedById;
@XmlElement(name = "CreatedById")
protected String createdById;
@XmlElement(name = "ModId")
protected Integer modId;
@XmlElement(name = "Id")
protected String id;
@XmlElement(name = "CustomInteger5")
protected Integer customInteger5;
@XmlElement(name = "CustomInteger6")
protected Integer customInteger6;
.... 100+ more
```

The user interface will have friendly names for these fields.  Names they are familiar with, because they are the field names for that record in the database.  Behind the scenes the UI will map UI field names to the XML names. If the UI were to send me a query string like this, `"CustomInteger5=some new value"`, how can I set this class member?

```
@XmlElement(name = "CustomInteger5")   
    protected Integer customInteger5;
```

I know I could have a bunch of if statements like:

```
if(requestStr.fieldName.equals("CustomInteger5"){   
      setCustomInteger5(rquestStr.value);   
}
```

...

This would be so much work though!  Can I set these class members dynamically if I provide the xml name as a String?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do what I wanted, but I was able to accomplish what I needed using the Java reflection API.  If anyone has a better solution, I am still interested in learning of it?  Here is he tutorial I went through to learn about reflection. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/